# I'm having problems downloading the Github AHK_X11 App on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: installation, crystal-lang

I downloaded Crystal with brew I don't think the error is related to that

`/usr/bin/ld: warning: libpcre.so.3, needed by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0, may conflict with libpcre.so.1 /root/.cache/crystal/crystal-run-build_namespace.tmp: error while loading shared libraries: libgc.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

When I get this error. When I type `./setup_dependencies.sh`

*I have tried so many ways I still can't figure it out I tried deleting Crystal and reinstalling it again but it didn't work because most likely the error is not there and I'm new to linux*

Comment: In case you aren't forced to use brew on Linux: If you don't need the latest version, installing directly from the packages "apt-get install crystal" is probably the easiest. If you need the latest Crystal version, snap is the best on Ubuntu IMHO: https://crystal-lang.org/install/on_ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are the same person (BySylex) as the author of this issue https://github.com/phil294/AHK_X11/issues/20, but anyway, you will find the solution in there. This is not your fault, but at the same time, you probably do not need to run `./setup_dependencies`. Instead, you can download AHK_X11 directly from the release section without having to build from source.